# Rails how to fetch data from model specified in form select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have this form select :

```
<%= form_with(model: task, local: true) do |form| %>

<%= form.select(:person_id, Person.all.collect {|c| [c.person_name, c.id]}, {prompt: "Select a person"}, {class: 'col-md-12'}) %>
```

In my task controller, in my create def, I'd want to be able to fetch the person_name but it turns out I can't. For example, I can fetch the id by doing @task.person_id, but I can't do @task.person_name. How would I achieve this? I'm thinking about maybe options_for_select or maybe collection_select, but I'm very unsure.

Anyone has an idea? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I fixed it by doing this in my def create of the controller :

```
name = @task.person_id
@person = Person.find(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change collect to select
may that helps
  @autoComplete =  Prom.select('promname').collect { |p| p.promname }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can access the person name by

```
@task.person.person_name
```

or if you want to get person name from task,

## add this in task.rb

```
def person_name
  self.person.person_name if !self.person_id.nil?
end
```

then you can use @task.person_name in your controller